# Why the Recursion in the function I declared is not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand recursion.

I am stuck with the following: I need to add up the numbers from a single number so if I call addUp(4) it should return 10 (4+3+2+1).

I came up with the below solution but it does not count the last number (1).
I know that the solution is to change the condition to "num===0" but I don't see the difference: in my head, my solution should work as well.

```js
function addUp(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    return num;
  }
  return num + addUp(num - 1);
}

console.log(addUp(4)); // 9
```

Comment: You are adding the `1`, but also the `-1`.

Comment: It includes both 1 and -1 which is making you think it doesn't include 1.

Comment: PS: this is a great place to use a debugger - you can step through, and see exactly, what is happening. It is imho a good way for obtaining a better understanding, of how such code functions.

Comment: Why am I adding -1. When I call addUp(2-1) it should be my "last recursion" since it should be addUp(1)

Comment: The recursion ends at `num < 0`, including (the call where that is true is the last). That means `addUp(-1)` is the last, and the previous sums `0 + addUp(0 - 1)` which is `0 + -1`, adding the `-1`.

Comment: I think I am there. Basically, when it calls addUp(-1) the function stop and provides the final number, -1 is included. In my head, I thought that first the condition was checked, and then the number was added.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check for less than or equal to zero. You want to stop if you hit zero as well. A log statement helps identify this.

Alternatively, you could evaluate `num < 1`.

```js
function addUp(num) {
  console.log(`Attempting to add: ${num}`);
  if (num <= 0) {
    return num;
  }
  console.log(`Added: ${num}`);
  return num + addUp(num - 1);
}

console.log(`Total: ${addUp(4)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Code golf

The following code is only 19 bytes:

`f=n=>n<1?n:n+f(n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this code and write it in one expression without recursion:

```js
function addUp(num) {
    return num*(num+1)/2;
}
```

Comment: That introduces floating-point arithmetic which is less-performant than simple register addition.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl are you sure ? integer division should not involve floating point maths (at least in java) - and division by 2 is just (or should be) a simple bit shift operation

Comment: 1.In JS all numbers are floating point

2.In modern CPUs floating point arithmetics is as fast (or nearly as fast) as integer arithmetics

3.Division can be slower than addition, but not as slow as you can think. In case you want better performance you can switch /2 to *0.5

Answer (score 1):

The stopping condition should be `num <= 0` and not `num < 0`.

```js
function addUp(num) {
  if (num <= 0) {
    return num;
  }
  return num + addUp(num - 1);
}

console.log(addUp(3));
```

#### FLOWCHART

[image]